# c++ string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, subscript

Please help with debugging. It gives me an error 'string subscript out of range error'.

The program needs to sort the text using insertion sort algorithm.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void insertionSort(string &text, int size) {
  char temp;
  int i;
  for(int j=1;j<size;j++)
  {
    //text.push_back(temp);
    temp=text[j];
    i=j-1;
   while(i>=0 && text[i]>temp)
 {

 text[i+1]=text[i];
  i--;
 }
    text[i+1]=temp;
  }
}

int main()
{
  string text="this a just text need to be sorted";

  int size = text.length();
  insertionSort(text,size);
  cout<<text<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

debug assertion Failed!

Line:1441:

Expression: string subscript out of range

I supposed to change `text[i+1]=text[j]`  to `text[i+1]=text[i]`;

Comment: Your code is badly formatted, and you don't indicate what part of your code is causing the problem.

Comment: You could make our life a lot easier if you pointed out where the error occurred and made the effort of formatting this better.

Comment: **Where** do you get this error message? Anyway ... the error says it all, you're outside of the string.

Comment: just revising the material, preparing to exams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
while(text[i]>temp && i>=0)
```

with

```
while(i>=0 && text[i]>temp)
```

Reason:

When i becomes negative, ie `i == -1`, then first check for `i>=0` instead of doing check for `text[i]>temp` (which tries to access array element at position -1 and gives out of range).

**EDIT:**

also replace

```
text[i+1]=text[j];
```

with

```
text[i+1]=text[i];
```

Why so ? : In [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) if we have entries greater than text[j] in the lower part (ie. 0 to j-1), then we need to push these entries ahead and stop at point when we no longer have elements bigger than text[j].

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't give a correct output, have to check loop again

Comment: @mydreamadsl : so the "string subscript out of range" is gone ?

Comment: @mydreamadsl see my EDIT above.

Comment: @mydreamadsl added explanation in EDIT. please read and understand so that you wont commit any mistakes in your exam..also best of luck :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to change this instruction:

```
text[i+1]=text[i];
```

Answer (score 2):

When `j == 1` your while loop starts with i==0, then you decrement `i` in the loop, then at the next execution of the loop you check for `text[i]`, which is invalid (`i == -1` here)

To fix, you need to check for the validity of `i` first:

```
while(i >=0 && text[i] > temp) {
  // ...
}
```

This does the right thing because the `&&` operator has a short-circuit rule: if the first operand (`i>=0` in this case) results in `false`, the rest of the expression (`text[i] > temp`) is not evaluated

Comment: @mydreamadsl : yes, please see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You've the information about the problem.The simple way to solve this is, to put some print statements to know the index values used with the string array.

Another comment is that, please don't pass the length of the string because if you call text.length(); inside the function prior to changing it can get the length of the string.